# Spring 4.2 combine multiple ListenableFutures

Tags: java, spring

I currently write an application using Spring 4.2 (with Java 1.6). It calls multiple providers which use Spring's @Async annotation to be processed in parallel each returning a [ListenableFuture](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) (all of the same type). Has Spring something similar to guava's [Futures.allAsList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(java.lang.Iterable)) to combine multiple futures in a single one? Or does Spring provide another concept for joining multiple ListenableFutures?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Java 8 CompletabaleFuture since ListenableFuture implements Future interface. You would call it: `CompletableFuture.allof(arrayOfYourFutures)` to get a single one. See [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Comment: Sounds good but I forgot to mention that I'm forced to use Java 6 (Websphere 8) - sorry :(

Comment: This causes a compilation error since `allof`method expects a `CompletableFuture` but not a `ListenableFuture`

Comment: Spring's `ListenableFuture` has the `.completable()` method which converts it to a CompletableFuture which can be used in `allOf`.